# keyboard mappings are totally screwed after updating to kde4

Tags: linux, keyboard, kde, x-windows, kde-4

I recently upgraded from KDE 3.5 to KDE 4, and I have been having weird issues with my keyboard.  In one of the virtual consoles e.g. when I press ctrl + alt 1 , I can type perfectly, but in KDE, several of the number keys don't work, the left and right arrows don't work either.

When I press the right arrow key in xev I get this:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
root 0x6f, subw 0x0, time 903459, (111,55), root:(115,836),
state 0x10, keycode 114 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,                                                                         
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                                
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I press the '3' key it toggles my Bookmarks toolbar in Firefox, in xev I get this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
root 0x6f, subw 0x0, time 999968, (94,115), root:(98,896),
state 0x10, keycode 12 (keysym 0x1008ff30, XF86Favorites), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                               
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                             
XFilterEvent returns: False                                                

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
root 0x6f, subw 0x0, time 1000032, (94,115), root:(98,896),
state 0x10, keycode 12 (keysym 0x1008ff30, XF86Favorites), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:                                               
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As this is deeper down, changing the type of keyboard in the KDE meun's has no effect.  I'm slowly beginning to wade through the mountains of documentation about the X keyboard model, but there has to be a better way. Does anyone no what it is?

Edit:

1234567890 !
after deleting the entire .kde folder.

but only until I change the Keyboard settings from the "system settings" applet, then its hosed full time.  Regardless of what I set the settings too.  (restore to default settings doesn't)

2nd Edit:

I'm using Gentoo AMD64,  I was upgrading from KDE 3.5 > KDE 4.2.
I think I had *manual* settings before, although I didn't change anything. I was originally running KDE without HAL until that stop working a year or so ago.  The only customisation I made was to set the multimedia keys to control Amarok.

3rd Edit

```
   $ grep xkb /var/log/Xorg.0.log
   (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
   (**) Option "xkb_model" "evdev"
   (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
   (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
   (**) Option "xkb_model" "evdev"
   (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
```

Xorg.0.log has this to say:

```
(WW) AllowEmptyInput is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
(WW) Disabling Mouse1
(WW) Disabling Keyboard1
```

My Xorg.conf has this in it.

```
    Identifier  "Keyboard1"
    Driver      "kbd"
    Option      "AutoRepeat" "500 30"
    # Specify which keyboard LEDs can be user-controlled (eg, with xset(1))
    Option      "XkbRules" "xorg"
    Option      "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option      "XkbLayout" "gb"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could:

1. **Move** these files from ~/.kde/share/config/  .. kxkbrc , khotkeysrc , khotkeys_update , and startupconfigkeys to another location

Then let KDE run defaults on next start up and go re-config your lyaout settings.

When I went from KDE 3.5 to 4.2 I had to remove some old configs to resolve a few issues, not this specifically, but in other K apps. Beyond that, try a new keyboard, just for fun.

Comment: not bad, but instead of deleting them, move them to different locations, eg, rename them all to *.bak.  if the OP customized functionality in the old config, it would be missing in KDE4's defaults, and having the old config around to compare might help get the functionality back.

Comment: I moved the whole folder, but we are only half way there,  see my edit.

Comment: Just curious here, what distro and KDE4 version are you using?

Comment: Also, are you using manual Xkb settings in your xorg.conf or doing it via HAL?

Comment: answers in question above.

Comment: I have two Gentoo AMD64 desktops w/ KDE4. What do you get when running ' grep xkb /var/log/Xorg.0.log  ' ? Mine has xkb_layout as 'us'. I have hal in my USE flags in make.conf myself, and xorg uses evdev to load up my xkb rules, I assume from settings in /etc/conf.d/keymaps . just curious if the underlying keymap config is causing you trouble.

Comment: HAL is in my make.conf too, I have edited the question again. I have also fixed all the revdep-rebuild errors, which makes the system more stable, but sadly doesn't fix this.

Comment: As a point of reference, my KDE 4.3.3 setting at System & Settings > Region & Language > Keyboard Layout . Layout is set to "Disable keyboard layouts" and my default model from my system is "pc104" with a layout of "us". I am not sure what to suggest at this point, other than sharing my config with you. My Xorg.0.log output is the same as yours. Have you tried a different physical keyboard? (as silly as that sounds)

Comment: So did you put [ Option "AllowEmptyInput" "false" ] in your xorg.conf? I see you approved my series of answers, but is it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

First, create another user account, log in and test if keymap works there. If yes, then the problem is in your private configs. That will localize the problem whether it's system-wide (/etc, /usr/share/kde*) or user (~).

Next, open keyboard preferences, change something, and close it: you'll have some default configuration in the new home folder. After backing up your personal folder, try to move these files: that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual consoles (tty) are completely unrelated to X11 and use a different keyboard mapping mechanism. Did you try starting a different desktop (twm/icewm/gnome whatever)?

Comment: True,  but I need to prove that the 3,4,5 keys on my keyboard are not broken,  jam in the switches etc.  They work fine in the tty.

Answer (score 0):

The 'state 0x10' implies that one of your modifier keys is stuck down.  I'm on OSX, but that state corresponds to my command key, which I think is mapped to the logo key on PC keyboards.  Try hitting the logo key a few times (or other modifiers, like alt or ctrl) until state returns to 0x00, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I so wanted this to be true, I almost accepted the answer before I tried it out, but sadly it isn't right. 'state 0x10' refers to the fact my num lock key is pressed down.   5 & 6 (the top line) still don't work, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by o_O Tync answer; Posted in case anyone else has this same issue.   I renamed my home directory as 'backup',  removed my account, recreated it.  Hacked passwd and groups so I have the same uid and gid, then moved all the *visible* files back.  Then I copy other apps hidden files if I think I need them.  Strangely it now works perfectly.